# How to change the text of parameter

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a database that has a query where a parameter box pops up. The parameter is  [Forms]![frmFA_Management]![Text0]. This works fine when the form is open, however when the form is not open, the parameter is useless since the users don't know what it is asking for. Is it possible to apply a cover text or a hint to it? I can't change the textbox name to be more useful since the database is old and poorly documented and I do not want to risk breaking anything.

Answer (score 0):

How does this query open and how is it being used? Is there a second form that opens it or are you manually opening the query?  Is it a source object for another object or is it just the query that is opening?

If it gets opened through another form and it is a source object, you could check to see if the first form is open through a click or onOpen event of the second form and if it isn't, store a variable from an input box and change the source object of the object.

```
If CurrentProject.AllForms("myform").IsLoaded = True
    myObject.SourceObject = myQuery
Else
    Dim input as string
    input = inputbox "Please enter a value for my field"
    myObject.SourceObject = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myField = " & input & ";"
Endif

myObject.Requery
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you drop the parameter from the query. As you WELL see once you add a parameter to a query, then it is married to some silly form that needs to be open. This means you can’t use the query for other reports, forms or even in code.

At the end of the day, such an approach results in a real mess.

And even if you could “cover” the prompt, what value do you want for the parameter anyway? (You have to supply it anyway, right?).

The REAL question is WHEN and WHERE are you using that query? If the query is being used for a form or report, then remove the criteria and then PASS a “where” clause to the given report.

So to open a report, you can go:

```
Docmd.OpenReport "rptManagers",acViewPreview
```

The above would open the report – no filter.

If you need some criteria, then add it such as:

```
Dim strWhere   as string

strWhere = "Manager = [forms]![frmFA_Management]![Text0]"
Docmd.OpenReport "rptManagers",acViewPreview,,strWhere
```

Or, just prompt for the value like:

```
Dim strWhere as string

strWhere = inputbox("Enter manager ")
if strWhere = "" then exit sub

strWhere = "Manager = '" & strWhere & "'"

Docmd.OpenReport "rptManagers",acViewPreview,,strWhere
```

The REAL beauty of using the “where” clause of the openform/openReport is you can add additional parameters (optional) and not have to modify or worry about the query prompting you.

Say:

```
strWhere = "Manager = 'Joe' and City = 'Edmonton'"
Docmd.OpenReport "rptManagers",acViewPreview,,strWhere
```

So by removing the parameters from the query, you get a HUGE increase in re-use. And better is you now can add or ignore parameters on the fly.

Once you add a forms! Reference inside of a query, you quite much destroyed the ability of re-use in your application since some silly form has to be open.

By simple adoption of the "where" clause, you will save tons of development cost, eliminate the issue when you don't want the filter, and better yet have a query that can be re-used in "many" places without some silly form having to be open. Placing forms! references in a query is however a GREAT way to rack up additional billing hours - it really makes a mess and increases costs by substantial amounts. So best is to remove the forms! reference in the query - and then no unexpected prompts will occur.

Answer (score -1):

Create a copy of the query.

Open the copy in **SQL** view.

Replace `[Forms]![frmFA_Management]![Text0]` with the parameter name of your choice, for example:

`[Enter value for xx]`.